# Fonts in Google Chrome messed up

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, fonts

I recently installed new fonts on my computer that my friend sent me so I can use them in Adobe Photoshop. When I downloaded the ".zip" folder containing the fonts I unzipped the folder, pressed Ctrl+A to highlight all of the font files and then I right clicked and clicked "Install". That is how I installed the fonts.

Now the fonts in Google Chrome are messed up. When I go on websites such as Stackoverflow, Facebook, etc. the fonts are different and look really odd. Random parts of text are bolded or italized, etc.

I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome and Windows 8 Pro.

I took 3 screenshots to show you what I mean.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

See if Control Panel (from the desktop) → Appearance and Personalization → Fonts → Font Settings (in left pane) → "Restore Default Font Settings" button helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you've replaced default system (like Verdana, Tahome etc.) fonts which where in archive

Comment: How do I fix that?