# Missing Calibri fonts in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-office-2013

I recently upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8, and installed Office 2013, both of which originated from a MSDN subscription. However, I noticed that I only have Calibri Light as a font, so the Calibri default body in Word is being replaced with Calibri Light. What happened to the regular Calibri? There is no Calibri.ttf file on my computer either.

Comment: I have the calibri font in Win8. Run the DISM commands to repair Windows and fix WinSxS issues: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx

Comment: Try to [Restore Default Font Settings](http://superuser.com/a/519156/138343).

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions but Calibri is still missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you haven't already found those font files, or for anyone else who has run into this problem, you should be able to find the files in your **C:\Windows\WinSxS** folder. Open that folder in File Explorer and the type **calibri** in the search box at the top right. It should find all of the original **calibri*.ttf** files from your Windows 8 installation. You can drag them from there into the Fonts folder.

On my system, the Office 2013 installer also deleted the **Constantia** font files. If that happened to you, then after reinstalling your Calibri files, enter **constan** in that search box and you will find the **constan*.ttf** files which you can also drag into your Fonts folder.

This is a serious bug in the Office 2013 installer. It should not be deleting existing fonts!

Comment: It isn't the Office 2013 installer that does this, but uninstalling Office 2010 after upgrading to Windows 8.