# Missing Cambria Math font in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts, microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-word-2016

Somewhat similar to [Missing Calibri fonts in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/520325/missing-calibri-fonts-in-windows-8). I just uninstalled Office 2010 and installed Office 2016 and now all my equations show up as blank or with boxes instead of the proper symbols.

[image: Cambria_Math_Missing_1]

[image: Cambria_Math_Missing_2]

It's clear that the Cambria Math font is missing (along with variants if any) for some reason. Probably the Office 2010 uninstaller is to [blame](https://superuser.com/questions/520325/missing-calibri-fonts-in-windows-8#comment713444_567370).

I have already searched in the **C:\Windows\WinSxS** folder as [recommended](https://superuser.com/a/567370) but no Cambria Math to be found there. So the question is, how do I fix this?

Comment: You can solve this problem by extract the install.wim from a Windows 7 installation and going to the WinSxS and grabbing the file that way.

Comment: I will follow your suggestion, just need to Google it first. Can't I just copy the fonts from my Windows 10 laptop? Or do they have to be from Windows 7 so that the versions match?

Comment: Ok, I will try as you suggest. Hopefully there will be no incompatibility, otherwise I will Google and follow your first solution. Thank you.